# MySql Query fetches twice the rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query.

```
select a.nume_echipament,
       a.producator,
       a.seria,
       b.uc,
       b.port,

       (select starea from echipamente order by data desc, ora desc limit 1) as starea,

       a.durata_aprovizionare,
       a.durata_viata,
      ( select data_aprov from aprovizionari where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by date(data_aprov) desc, time(ora_aprov) desc limit 1) as data_aprov,


      ( select ora_aprov from aprovizionari where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by date(data_aprov) desc, time(ora_aprov) desc limit 1) as ora_aprov,
       sec_to_time(count(starea)*5)  as durata_totala 

       from date_tehnice a
       inner join echipamente b on a.nume_echipament=b.nume_echipament
       inner join aprovizionari c on c.nume_echipament=a.nume_echipament
       where a.nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere'
       and
       b.starea='1'
       and
       b.data > c.data_aprov
       and
       b.ora >c.ora_aprov   
       ;
```

The problem is it fetches the rows twice. It affects my 'durata_totala'(total lifetime) variable, because instead of getting for eg 00:00:05 i get 00:00:10.
I have a table where '1' represents that the equipment is on,0 otherwise.
That's why i have count(starea*5). Because my arduino sends data every 5 seconds to the database.

Can someone help me with a solution?

Comment: How many rows do you return from `echipamente` and `aprovizionari` where `nume_echipamente` = 'automat_imbuteliere'? This could be the result of a non-granular join.

Comment: Do you have constraints on echipamente and aprovizionari that make nume_echipament unique? You probably have more than 1 record with nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' in echipamente or aprovizionari.

Comment: @chipmunkofdoom2 thank you, that was the problem... i had duplicates on in table 'aprovizionari' on nume_echipament